# When adding a new Entry, I'm having an error

Tags: entries

I'm new at Craft and I want to add new Entry into a jobs section. But I'm always receiving en error message.

[image]

```
{% extends '_layouts/site' %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
    {% set company = entry.company %}
    {% set jobDescription = entry.jobdescription %}
    {% set jobRequirements = entry.jobrequirements %}
    {% set location = entry.location %}
    {% set salary = entry.salary %}
    {% set email = entry.email %}
    <span><strong>{{ company }}</strong> &nbsp; - &nbsp;{{ entry.postDate.rfc1123 }}</span>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span><strong>Description</strong><br/>{{ jobDescription }}</span>
    <span><strong>Requirements</strong><br/>{{ jobRequirements }}</span>
    <span><strong>Location</strong><br/>{{ location }}</span><br/>
    <span><strong>Contact us at</strong><br/> {{ email }}</span>
    <br/><span><strong>Salary</strong><br/>{{ salary }}</span>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just based on your screenshot, my guess is the settings for your entry type for your "Jobs" section has "Show the Title field" unchecked and you've set the "Title Format" setting to be "jobs".

I'm not sure if you unchecked that box on purpose, but if you re-check it, you can manually set the Title (which the slug is auto-generated from on new entries) on a per-entry basis.

Comment: I try to unchecked it and it display an 404 error message

Comment: What displays a 404 error message? Editing the entry? Saving it? Saving the section settings page? Maybe post a screenshot of your job section settings along with the entry type section settings?

Comment: I tried to create another entry with the same details . I can create a new entry now but the problem is i'm having an error: "Variable "entries" does not exist"

Comment: I already edit my post . my code is already there

Comment: Hi brad . It's okay now . I just want to ask how can i get all the data in an entry?

Comment: @lanceadriannedelacruz, please consider accepting Brad's answer if it solved your problem, and post separately if you have an entirely different question.